# How can I stop my NSTimer thread from further executing the selector

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nstimer

Currently I am creating a NSTimer that calls my method every one second.

I do this like so:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(clocktick) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

How can I stop this from calling `clocktick`?

I have tried assigning it like so: `NSTimer *myTimer = [NSTimer ...` and then using `myTimer = nil;` but that did nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `[myTimer invalidate]` that will kill the timer for you.

Answer (score 3):

You have to hold a reference to it, and then send the `invalidate` message to it:

```
[myTimer invalidate];
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using 'invalidate' ([timerInstance invalidate]; for example)?

Or is the problem that you don't have a reference to the timer instance anymore?

Comment: You could either create a private property to hold a reference to the timer in your class. Or have the function you are calling accept NSTimer* as a parameter. That way you could cancel the timer within the function the timer is calling every second. (For example: -(void) targetMethod:(NSTimer *) theTimer { ... })